# Accidential CHMOD 755

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

Alright, I accidentially chomdded everything to 755, which isn't as terrible as chowning everything to the local user. How insecure is this and how would I restore it easily, without reinstalling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reinstall is the best option. I personally would always have the nagging feeling of something not done right even if the following work.

1. Use another Ubuntu system to reference your permissions. Same Ubuntu version and architecture.

   `reference$ find / ! -type l \
            -path "^/tmp" -prune \
            -o -path "^/dev" -prune \
            -o -path "^/sys" -prune \
            -o -printf "%m %p\n" > /root/perms.txt`
2. copy `/root/perms.txt` to your main system
3. Use `/root/perms.txt` to reference and modify permissions

   `main$ cat /root/perms.txt | while read LINE; do
   perm=echo -E "$LINE" | awk '{print $1}'
   filename=echo -E "$LINE" | sed 's/^$perm //'`

   if [ -a $filename ]; then
       echo -E "$filename" >> /root/chmod-success.log
       chmod $perm $filename
   else
       echo -E "$filename" >> /root/chmod-failure.log
   fi
   done
4. check the errors in `/root/chmod-success.log` and `/root/chmod-failure.log`

Anyway, there are just too many edge cases here that I cannot even imagine if this would work perfectly. Test on another non-production system first. And test on the main production system without the `chmod $perm $filename` line first

Comment: +1 for reinstall.  I've done exactly the same thing, and after banging my head against the wall for 2 days trying to right all the wrongs, I wound up reinstalling anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an RPM based distro like Fedora/Redhat or CentOS you could run

```
rpm -qa | xargs rpm --setperms
```

That will fix all files that were installed via rpm.. the rest will have to be fixed by hand

Comment: The tag says "ubuntu-server". And `rpm -a --setperms`.